# jQuery Selected Option From Dropdown and display to another label

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

First of all this question might be noob because i only have basic in JS.

The question is, i already create Category data in Thrust's page which only have 4IR and DEB. Which mean in Thrust DB, it have category_id.

So in this page, when i select Thrust, it should show Category that link with Thrust.

But for this case, when i select Thrust, the Category does not appear. Am i doing something wrong here? Im so lost right now

```js
   $("#pilih1").change(function() {

            var thrus_id = $(this).val();
            var thrusts = @json($thrusts->toArray());
            $("#pilih2").html(``);
            thrusts.forEach(thrust => {
                console.log(thrusts);
                if (thrust.thrus_id == thrus_id) {
                    $("#pilih2").append(`
                        <option value="` + thrust.id + `">` + thrust.category + `</option>
                    `);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
     <div class="mb-3 row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="namaStrategy">Strategy Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:30%">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="namaStrategy" />

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="thrus_id">Thrust</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:30%">
                        <select class="form-control" name="thrus_id" id="pilih1">
                            <option selected disabled hidden>PLEASE CHOOSE</option>

                            @foreach ($thrusts as $thrust)
                                <option value="{{ $thrust->id }}">{{ $thrust->namaThrust }}</option>
                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="">Category</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:30%">
                        <select class="form-control" name="category" id="pilih2">
                            <option selected disabled hidden>PLEASE CHOOSE</option>
                            <option value="DEB">DEB</option>
                            <option value="4IR">4IR</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: It is hard to help because there is much of your code we can't see.  But I notice one thing - you are first comparing `thrust.thrus_id`, and then using `thrust.id`.  Do they really both exist, or should they be the same?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Can i know what else should i show ? It should be the same actually

Comment: The problem is really just HTML/JS, the PHP part is not relevant here. PHP code here doesn't tell us anything, in fact it makes it harder bcs we can't see the generated HTML. Likewise we don't know what is the structure of `$thrusts` that you are using in JS.  Try to create a simplified, *minimal* copy of your code, with HTML rendered, so we can actually run it and debug it, with say a small sample of whatever `@json($thrusts->toArray())` generates (or dummy data if it is private) ... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Your code is working fine .